# exactly once semantics in Kafka source connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

After reading about Kafka idempotent operation and the transactions I wanted to see if Kafka source connectors use any of them in order to ensure exactly-once semantics.

After A little bit of reading, I found out that the source connector uses some kind of "offset" of is own which let it store the last operation it did, And then I saw that the [Debezium source connector for MongoDB](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.0/connectors/mongodb.html) can only achieve at least once semantics.

So my question is why can't the MongoDB source connector guarantee exactly-once semantics? if the connector can commit its offset alongside every message with a transaction it can ensure that both the message and the offset are inside Kafka for sure and thus guaranteeing exactly-once semantics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [KIP-618](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-618%3A+Exactly-Once+Support+for+Source+Connectors) for source connectors, and 318 to make the producer of connectors idempotent

Kafka is an append only log. If the source connector dies between producing the event and committing the offset as part of normal consumer operations, then there's a potential that the consumer will need to reset back to the last uncommitted offset

Comment: I get that if the action isn't "atomic" you can crash between pushing the event and committing the offset. But [this article](https://www.confluent.io/blog/exactly-once-semantics-are-possible-heres-how-apache-kafka-does-it/) mentions transactions in Kafka that let you send a batch of messages that all go thru or all fail, which let let you solve the problem if crashing between the committing the event and committing the offset.(correct my if I am wrong)

Comment: Kafka Connect does not implement the transactional producer. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-318%3A+Make+Kafka+Connect+Source+idempotent

Comment: I see, that's a shame could of been really useful. The KIP seems to be very old should I wait to see how it develops or is this KIP destined to fail?(I am new to the opensource concept so I am not sure what to expect of it)

Comment: @nhruo You can follow-up on the Kafka-dev mailing list linked there, if you would like

Comment: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-618%3A+Exactly-Once+Support+for+Source+Connectors